# 4-polytopes with only one kind of regular facet

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, polytopes

Is there a neat way to show (or a reference that already proves) that

- the 4-cube is the only convex 4-polytope in which all facets are *regular* 3-cubes?
- the [24-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-cell) is the only convex 4-polytope in which all facets are *regular* octahedra?
- the [120-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/120-cell) is the only convex 4-polytope in which all facets are *regular* dodecahedra?

Note that I do require that the facets are *regular*, so e.g. just any cubical polytope does not fit.

I am aware of [Gosset's semiregular polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiregular_polytope) (vertex-transitive and all facets are regular polytopes), for which this statement is true, but I do not require vertex-transitivitiy here.

However, if my statement turns out to be wrong in this general form, then I wonder whether it holds when I require that all vertices are on a common sphere.

Answer (score 5):

This is Theorem 1 (actually, Satz 1) of Roswitha Blind, Konvexe Polytope mit kongruenten regulären $(n- 1)$-Seiten im $\Bbb{R}^n$ $(n \ge 4)$, *Comment. Math. Helvetici* 54 (1979) 304--308.  The short proof follows from two short lemmas, one of which cites Coxeter's *Regular Polytopes* and an article by Shephard.

You might also be interested in a related [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296444/the-johnson-polychora) from last year with helpful links, which references a second 1979 paper of Blind in her program to explore the analogue of Johnson solids for 4-polytopes.

Answer (score 0):

Within 4D we also have the bipyramid on a tetrahedral base, as well as the bipyramid on an icosahedral base, which both use 8 or 40 tetrahedra solely.

In the papers of the Blind couple there are further polytopes, with various regular facets listed too. But your restriction to just a single type of facets and your restriction to 4D comes down to just these 2, except of the six 4D regular polytopes - at least if you'd further restrict to convexity.

--- rk